# Unable to create a new machine into Hyper-v

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, centos7, hyper-v

I can't install cent os into hyper-v virtual machine

[The error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmUrI.png)

```
want to get back to the point of automatic control precedent automatic control point- virtual centos machine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand french, but for other's sake, what happens when you click on "Continue", did you turn off the VM while updating, this results from a checkpoint (point de controle) being created.